# Need to rearrange collection of pixles in neighbouring order

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my Unity project, I processed an image to get the border pixels in a queue. The problem is, these pixels form the border, but aren't in linear order. I can't trace the border using them. I need to sort them in such a way that from 1st pixel, rest all should be linearly one after another.

So what I have done:

1. Floodfilled the object in image with green color and while doing so, stored the pixels turning green in a queue. What I can see on screen is green shape on white background.
2. Used following code on this queue to get border pixels:

   ```
   private static Queue<Point> BorderFill(Texture2D tex1, Queue<Point> qu1)
   {
       var qt = new Queue<Point>();

       while (qu1.Count > 0) 
       {
           Point c1    = qu1.Dequeue ();
           Color right = tex1.GetPixel (c1.x + 1, c1.y);
           Color left  = tex1.GetPixel(c1.x-1, c1.y);
           Color up    = tex1.GetPixel(c1.x, c1.y+1);
           Color down  = tex1.GetPixel (c1.x, c1.y - 1);

           if (left != Color.green || up != Color.green || down != Color.green || right != Color.green)
               qt.Enqueue (new Point (c1.x, c1.y));
       }
        return qt;
   }
   ```
3. This function gave me the queue that has the border pixels.
4. I need them to be reordered.

I am coding in C#.

Comment: Could you share some code?

Comment: So, the pixels in your que, how are they arranged? How are imported, post some code if u need actual help

Comment: @NeerajaKarandikar a Quick question, as you are trying to re order a Queue list it negate its meaning by what Queue is, how about you save your point in a List<Point> and sort it with .OrderBy(p => p.x).ThenBy(p => p.y)? and if you need the resulting list in Queue you can convert it with Queue<Point>(listName) alternative: you can use OrderBy(p => Math.Atan2(p.X, p.Y)).ToList(); to sort it clockwise

Comment: I could try this. Will it work for odd shaped border, like amoeba, where next pixel might have x,y value lower than before?

Comment: The alternative solution with  OrderBy(p => Math.Atan2(p.X, p.Y)).ToList() should work, give it a try, and inform me about the results

Comment: OrderBy(p => Math.Atan2(p.X, p.Y)).ToList()  is not giving correct order. I checked it